# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' in Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-functions, serverless

I am refering a C# library project from my Azure Function (Service bus queue trigger). The library is referencing the Newtonsoft nuget version 10.0.1.
While running the function locally on my visual studio, it gives this error .

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"}
```

I tried downgrading to version 10.0.0, but the issue is there.

I stumbled upon this issue link : https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/107. 
And tried downgrading to 9.0.1. But even then the error still occurs.

Note: The library project reference several other library projects which are also referencing Newtonsoft. I am keeping the same version of the nuget all the sub projects.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Please check your all library projects present in the solution. Keep latest stable version of `Newtonsoft.Json` in all referenced project and in your project.

Comment: Want to make sure; are you seeing this at build time? Can you share more details on when this is coming up (as there are a couple of possible issues here)

Comment: @FabioCavalcanteThis happens at runtime.

Comment: To be clear, you still see the error loading 10.0.0.0 when you downgrade to 9.0.1? Or is it a different error? Does it repro if you run locally?

Comment: @FabioCavalcante When 9.0.1 is referenced, its working. Earlier it was still referring to version 10 dll even after downgrading the nuget. Didnt notice the dll version earlier. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointing all the Newtonsoft dlls in all the sub libraries to version to 9.0.1 solved the issue.