# Unable to load Entity Framework Core into C# azure function

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I already opened an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2658) in [`Azure/azure-functions-host`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/) and I have a [repo](https://github.com/mamodom/AzureFunctionEFErrorRepro) with the repro steps, but I'm posting this here in case there is something inherently wrong with what I'm doing, or someone has already stumbled open this issue.

**My goal**: I want to run in an azure function some code that lives in a class library in an existing visual studio solution.

This code happens to use entity framework core in order to read and write to a SQL Server database.

While trying to isolate the issues I was facing, I ended up with the following scenario:

Repro steps:

1. In Visual Studio: File > New > Project > Azure Functions
2. Select `Azure Functions v2 Preview (.NET Core)`
3. Select `Http trigger`
4. Select `Storage Emulator`
5. Select Access rights `Function`
6. Install using nuget `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `2.0.2`
7. Add an invocation to anything from the `EFCore` package

   In my case I added the following line:

   ```
   log.Info(typeof(DbContext).AssemblyQualifiedName);
   ```
8. Ensure the azure storage emulator is running
9. Run the function from visual studio (`F5`)
10. Hit the url printed in the console

**Expected behavior**: along with the default behavior of the example `Http trigger` function I expect to see the following line printed with each invocation:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
```

**Actual behavior**: the app throws an exception at runtime and outputs the following

> [11-Apr-18 6:33:59 AM] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=6faabfd8-eb96-4d71-906c-940028a7978a)
>   [11-Apr-18 6:33:59 AM] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=6faabfd8-eb96-4d71-906c-940028a7978a)
>   [11-Apr-18 6:33:59 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. FunctionApp1: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Current conjecture: while researching this issue I found something that might be related:

The Azure functions runtime already has a set of packages available, one of those being `Newtonsoft.Json` in a specific version. In the case a newer version of `Newtonsoft.Json` is referenced from the project a similar behavior is observed.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47351068/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-10-0-0-0-culture-neut)'s a StackOverflow question. 
[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2529#issuecomment-373182486)'s a github issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround: For `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` roll back to version 2.0.1. Don't know if it is a known EFCore issue, but rolling back to 2.0.1 helped med with the exact same issue.